# Why are My jQuery Fade Transitions Not Smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the functions fadeIn() and fadeOut() in my script, but for unknown reasons, the animations aren't fluid. I uploaded my site [here](https://echinoid-resistance.000webhostapp.com/)

When the user clicks on a tag like "All", "Webdesign" or "3D animation", the tiles are supposed to fade away smoothly, and fade in smoothly too. but this is not happening, as follows:

```
$('a[worktypeselector]').click(function(){
    var worktypeAttr = $(this).attr("worktypeselector");
    $("span.tag").removeClass("tag-active");
    $("span.tag", this).addClass("tag-active");
    if(worktypeAttr=="all"){
        $("a[worktype]").fadeIn(500);
    }else{
        $("a[worktype]").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("worktype").indexOf(worktypeAttr) === -1){
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
            }else{
                $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can please explain why the script is not producing the expected results and what the remedy is? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try sharing the source code in question so we don't have to dig around your site for it?

Comment: sorry, i edited my post

Comment: You are getting conflicts with your `transition` rules on many of the classes you are trying to `fadeIn()`. Remove those and possibly that call to `delay()`. Your js code here seems good after a quick look.

Comment: It works well ! Thank you ! Sorry for that question, I'm just new to Javascript and jQuery

Comment: Why dont you post a demo of your code such as JS fiddle.
this is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/WApJa/).